# ansible created password for a user does not work for ssh sessions

Tags: ssh, ansible

I know this question has been asked several times, however, i am still having the issue w**here Users created using ansible** and **password setup** referenced to [ansible doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module) article is not working for ssh sessions.

I understand the password has to be hashed rather than the plain text. i tried following however still can't ssh to remote host.

```
---
- hosts: all #modify your server list
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    #created using the sha-512
    password: $6$i77J0vHI5M$/cWpyM72mGY5h8V6PW1KTg3Tjh6VH5jtdBTm2nLwjxKzW/iR2zbzm2X.eUYT833xEDaco5NxZgY.obtDNhPNz0
  tasks:
  - include_vars: users.yml
  - name: Creating users to Jump Server
    user: name="{{ item.username}}" password= "{{ password }}" state=present
    with_items: "{{ users }}"

  - name: Placing SSH Key to Authorized Key
  #please note that this code assumes as if the public-private key pair is generated, all public users (created above) have public keys copied at one place i.e. keyfiles directory for the ease
    authorized_key: user="{{item.username}}" key="{{ lookup('file', './keyfiles/authorized_keys.{{ item.username}}.pub')}}"
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

> /etc/shadow looks like this on all hosts

```
root@serverX:/home# cat /etc/shadow | grep sam
sam::17393:0:99999:7:::
```

What am i doing wrong or missing? I Will appreciate if someone can put some light. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the way. there was a small syntax error. Tried the password variable as `password={{ password }}` **instead of putting in quotation marks**.

Now the `/etc/shadow` file had same hashed password generated as set in variable.

```
root@serverX:/home# cat /etc/shadow | grep sam
sam:$6$i77J0vHI5M$/cWpyM72mGY5h8V6PW1KTg3Tjh6VH5jtdBTm2nLwjxKzW/iR2zbzm2X.eUYT833xEDaco5NxZgY.obtDNhPNz0:17393:0:99999:7:::
```

Hopefully this will help someone else too.

Comment: Quotes didn't mess anything, it's the space that you put after `=` that was the culprit.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use your password variable directly instead of `hash` using the `password_hash` filter:

Your password variable:

```
password: "my_secure_password"
```

Then modified your user creation task:

```
  - name: Creating users to Jump Server
    user:
      name: "{{ item.username}}"
      password: "{{ password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      state: present
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

Comment: Hi @Arbab, thanks for your post. I wanted to ask one thing as what is the difference in between `password={{ some_variable }}` and `password="{{ some_variable }}"` written in quotes ? My code above worked without quotes.

Comment: @rulebreaker4 I have change the task to pure YAML format, try to run the task in above format with and without quotes and you will see the error that ansible will generate.